# jQuery: Issue Using Bind & Click Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea why this click event isn't working?  (I'm sure the answer is obvious - I'm just not seeing it).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('h1').bind('click', function(){
                    alert('clicked');
                });
            )};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: @Stefan: thanks for catching this typo.  I need to remember to have firebug open next time.  Thanks for suggesting jsfiddle.net.  Looks like a cool site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('h1').bind('click', function(){
                    alert('clicked');
                });
            });//note this line
```

Looks like a typo. Open up firebug, and you should see a JS error.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WpJyj/).

Comment: Almost any IDE would have caught this error. I use Intelli-J Ultimate, and I recommend it highly for JS development with server stuff (it catches a few things Eclipse and Netbeans do not).

Comment: I can never tell when those brackets are properly closed without staring for a few minutes—they make me dizzy...